# Clipping of clients' updates in DP-FedAvg

Tags: tensorflow-federated

In the paper `Learning differentially private recurrent language models` that presents the algorithm `DP-FedAvg`, clipping of clients' updates seems to take place at the client side. Each client clips his local update and then returns the already clipped update back to the server.

However, in the other paper, `Advances and open problems in federated learning`, it seems that the server is the one clipping the updates. The paper says in page 48,
"With this technique, the server clips the L2 norm of individual updates, aggregates the clipped updates, and then adds Gaussian noise to the aggregate".

Which process is the one followed in `TFF` ? Who is performing the clipping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherent in TFF that would prevent either of the options you mention; both can be implemented.

If you asked about concrete available APIs, then `tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory.gaussian_fixed` creates aggregator applying clipping to a fixed norm *at clients*, before the values are aggregated.

Comment: This means that the default API ```DifferentiallyPrivateFactory.gaussian_fixed``` is implemented such that each client clips the update before sending it to the server for aggregation ?
 
What about the ```tff.utils.build_dp_query``` in ```TFF 0.18```, does it follow the same approach ?

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: yes. That deprecated functionality is now available in the `gaussian_fixed` and `gaussian_adaptive` classmethods of `DifferentiallyPrivateFactory`.